# SharePoint All Day Event gives obscure result

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm using the following code to create an All Day Event in a SharePoint calendar:

```
newitem = listobject.Items.Add()
guid = System.Guid.NewGuid()
            newitem["Name"] = "All Day Event " + guid.ToString()
            newitem["Title"] = "All Day Event " + guid.ToString()
            newitem["Start Time"] = System.DateTime.Now.Date
            newitem["End Time"] = System.DateTime.Now.Date
            newitem["Description"] = "Created by Automation Script"
            newitem["Location"] = "Location " + guid.ToString()
            newitem["UID"] = guid
            newitem["All Day Event"] = 1
            newitem.Update()
            print newitem["Created"]
```

However, when I query for the Created date of the created item (as in the last line ), it gives me the time in UTC. But in case of a Normal event or a recurrent event it gives me the local time. I tried to find the Kind property of the DateTime object, but it is set to Unspecified. The same problem occurs even if an All Day Event is created through the SharePoint site (manually). So I came to a conclusion that there is nothing wrong in the code. Please help me.

Comment: @Prabhu: When reformatting wasn't sure if your code was C# or something else. Please edit if it's not correct.

Comment: Also not sure why the `sharepoint-designer` tag is there.

Comment: @Prabhu: OK restored your original formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

[SO SharePoint - all day events behave differently in CAML query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520651/sharepoint-all-day-events-behave-differently-in-caml-query)

Comment: Thanks Ryan.. That gave me a great relief